# Autosize column in ListView (UWP)

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, layout, uwp

I would like to arrange my items in a ListView with a Text and an image like in this example:

[image]

- The first column is automatic, so it expands to the widest element.
- The second column should expand to fill the remaining space.

So, how can I make an Auto column... or simulate it?

Obviously, the difficult part of this layout is that different elements have their widths depending on other element's widths.

EDIT: Using @WPInfo's answer, I've tried with this:

**XAML**

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel></local:MainViewModel>
</Page.DataContext>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"  />
                <Border Background="CornflowerBlue" Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

**CODE:**

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public IList<string> Items { get; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new List<string>()
        {
            "ABC",
            "ABCDEF",
            "ABCDEFGHI",
        };
    }
}
```

The expected result was:

[image]

However, the actual result is:

[image]

The goal is that the first column to be as wide as the widest element inside it.

In WPF, this is solved easily with the use of `Grid.SharedSizeGroup`. In UWP there is not such a thing.

Comment: Have you thought about using RelativePanel?

Comment: How would you use it? Please, take the code in the OP :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ListView children don't know anything about each other. There's no simple trick to have all the items know what the longest text item is, so a more complicated solution is required. The following works. It will determine a fixed TextBlock size based on the largest item from the string list, and it will update it should the font size change. Obviously a simpler solution closer resembling your example code can be had if you decide on a fixed column size for either the text or the image, but I assume you already know that.

XAML:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel></local:MainViewModel>
</Page.DataContext>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="{Binding ItemFontSize, Mode=OneWay}" Width="{Binding TextWidth, Mode=OneWay}"  />
                <Border Background="CornflowerBlue" Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

C# ViewModel

```
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MyListViewItemsClass> Items { get; set; }

        private List<string> ItemsFromModel;

        private int _myFontSize;
        public int MyFontSize
        {
            get { return _myFontSize; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _myFontSize)
                {
                    _myFontSize = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("MyFontSize");
                    // Font size changed, need to refresh ListView items
                    LoadRefreshMyListViewItems();
                }
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            // set default font size
            _myFontSize = 20;

            // example data
            ItemsFromModel = new List<string>()
        {
            "ABC",
            "ABCDEF",
            "ABCDEFGHI",
        };

            LoadRefreshMyListViewItems();
        }

        public void LoadRefreshMyListViewItems()
        {
            int itemMaxTextLength = 0;
            foreach (var modelItem in ItemsFromModel)
            {
                if (modelItem.Length > itemMaxTextLength) { itemMaxTextLength = modelItem.Length; }
            }
            Items = new ObservableCollection<MyListViewItemsClass>();
            // Convert points to pixels, multiply by max character length to determine fixed textblock width
            // This assumes 96 DPI. Search for how to grab system DPI in C# there are answers on SO. 
            double width = MyFontSize * 0.75 * itemMaxTextLength;
            foreach (var itemFromModel in ItemsFromModel)
            {
                var item = new MyListViewItemsClass();
                item.MyText = itemFromModel;
                item.ItemFontSize = MyFontSize;
                item.TextWidth = width;
                Items.Add(item);
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("Items");
        }

        public class MyListViewItemsClass
        {
            public string MyText { get; set; }
            public int ItemFontSize { get; set; }
            public double TextWidth { get; set; }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, e);
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Comment: Whoops, that is so tricky and makes the ViewModel too coupled to the View :(

Comment: @SuperJMN Hmm. However, without doing this it's hard for your ListView to understand how it should render itself.  Using "auto" it will adjust itself based on your content, which is not what you need.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I wonder how some controls like "DataGrids" out there achieve the effect. As you know, those controls have a sense of columns in which the width of an item can affect the width of the rest.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting `ItemContainerStyle` property for the ListView:

```
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Then your ListView may look like this:

```
    <ListView x:Name="list">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock ... />
                    <Image Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" ... />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

After that, you can set a proper value for `HorizontalAlignment` property of your ListView.

Comment: Hey @WPFInfo! please, check the updated OP. I've tried your answer and it doesn't work. I've replaced the images by a border for the code to be easier to test and see the problem. Thanks!